# Acumatica2021R2 CreateSalesOrder action is not defined in OpportunityMaint

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

In the new version Acumatica 2021R2, the function `CreateSalesOrders` is not defined in `OpportunityMaint` graph, and I need add default values from `Products` to Solines in the olders version this it work but now I get error the function doesn't exist in the graph, I see that function exist in `PX.Objects.CR.Extensions.CRCreateSalesOrder` but is an abstract class and I don't find an implementation or this is in metadata

**Old code**

```
public delegate IEnumerable createSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter);

[PXOverride]
public virtual IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter, createSalesOrder baseMethod)
{
    PXTrace.WriteInformation("try ");

    PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOOrderEntry>((graph) =>
    {
        graph.RowInserted.AddHandler<SOOrder>((sender, e) =>
        {
            SOOrder order = (SOOrder)e.Row;
            SOOrderExt orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(order);

            orderExt.UsrCustomOne = "Howdy";  //assign anything you want here*/
        });
    });

    return baseMethod(adapter);
 }
```

But this raises an error

> The actions is not defined in the Graph OpportunityMaint

Now the action is in an [abstract class CRCreateSalesOrder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcree.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generic graph,
In OpportunityMaint you will see a line like

```c#
public class CRCreateSalesOrderExt : CRCreateSalesOrder<OpportunityMaint.Discount, OpportunityMaint, CROpportunity>
```

This extends the abstract generic graph and applies it's logic(including the createSalesOrder action) to the OpportunityMaint graph.

You should be able to override it with something like:

```c#
    public class CRCreateSalesOrderExt_Ext: PXGraphExtension<CRCreateSalesOrderExt, OpportunityMaint>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;

        public delegate IEnumerable createSalesOrderDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

        [PXOverride]
        public IEnumerable createSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter, createSalesOrderDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            //Add your handler here

            return baseMethod(adapter);
        }
    }
```

CRCreateSalesOrderExt comes from the PX.Objects.CR.OpportunityMaint(defined on the graph) and is the graph extension that inherits from the generic graph CRCreateSalesOrder, and OpportunityMaint is the base graph.

Comment: Thank you so much,
I had tried to extend the class but didn't know how to do it, it works fine :)